# LinqToSql - Bit of a strange behavior

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to run the following code. But the code breaks

```
    Dim complaints = From comp In Me.Db.Complaints _
    Let varX = GetVariations().WithVariationId(If(comp.ItemPropertyXVariationId, 0)) _
    Let varY = GetVariations().WithVariationId(If(comp.ItemPropertyYVariationId, 0)) _
    Select New Hogia.Retail.POS.Data.Complaint() With _
    {.ItemXVariation = If(varX Is Nothing, DirectCast(String.Empty, String), varX.Name)}
```

.ItemXVariation is a property of string type. Now i tested this line of code outside the LINQ statement in the following manner and it worked fine, returned the proper result as i expected

```
    Dim varXX = GetVariations().WithVariationId(0)
    Dim varYY = GetVariations().WithVariationId(0)
    Dim temp As New Complaint() With {.ItemXVariation = If(varXX Is Nothing, DirectCast(String.Empty, String), varXX.Name)}
```

Could someone please help me understand why the code in the first block breaks. what is wrong in there.

Here is the message that comes up (help me make sense out of this)

Could not translate expression 'Table(Complaint).Select(comp => new VB$AnonymousType_2`2
(comp = comp, varX = Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.Linq.IQueryable`1[
Data.ItemPropertyVariation]])).WithVariationId((comp.ItemPropertyXVariationId ?? 0)))).Select($VB$It1 => new VB$AnonymousType_3`2($VB$It1 = $VB$It1, varY = Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Data.ItemPropertyVariation]])).WithVariationId(($VB$It1.comp.ItemPropertyYVariationId ?? 0)))).
Select($VB$It => new Complaint() {ItemXVariation = 
IIF((Convert($VB$It.$VB$It1.varX) = null), null, $VB$It.$VB$It1.varX.Name)})' 
into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.

Comment: Remove as much of your code as possible but still leaving enough that the problem continues to occur and edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Is GetVariations() a method of your own.  linq to sql will be trying to call it as a stored procedure.

You'd need to either write a stored procedure, or get the full entity set then use linq (to objects) with your "let" statements. That would call your GetVariations()

Comment: Yes David, GetVariations() is my own function and returns an IQueryable of custom type. The culprit in this whole debacle seems to be 
If(varX Is Nothing, DirectCast(String.Empty, String), varX.Name) which translates to 
IIF((Convert($VB$It.$VB$It1.varX) = null), null, $VB$It.$VB$It1.varX.Name
When i use the same if statement outside linq query, it works absolutely fine. only inside linq query, it blows up

Answer (score 1):

It's a common misunderstanding that you would be able to use anything against IQueryable, and that it simply gets 'magically translated'. That is not the case.

The problem is that you use code that the Linq2SQL Linq provider does not support.

Simply put, Linq works by interpreting the expression tree defined in your query into it's target language (in the case of Linq2Sql, T-SQL). It cannot simply translate any method call into the appropriate sql...

So when using linq2sql (or any other linq provider for that matter), you should be aware of which query operators are supported, and how.

For a more in-depth explanation about the translation to Sql, [check out this blog post](http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/billwagner/archive/2006/08/26/linqtosql-translating-c-to-sql.aspx)

Comment: jeroenh i understand your point. But in my case the method call translates absolutely fine. it is ".ItemXVariation = If(varX Is Nothing, DirectCast(String.Empty, String), varX.Name)" that breaks the execution. .ItemXVariation is a property of string type. And all i want to do here is check if varX object is nothing then return an empty string, otherwise return the value in varX.Name to .itemXVariation. The strange thing is if i test the same line outside LINQ statement, it actually works, but not inside the statement. Any thoughts on that